# Smallville Season 09 Alternate Timeline

Tags: smallville

In the alternate timeline in season 9 of Smallville, which we saw via Lois' memories, how did Zod and his followers have powers under a red sun?

Does blue kryptonite cause one to have abilities under a red sun, as Zod and his men were laced with blue kryptonite?

Keep in mind that in this alternate timeline Zod did not receive a transfusion from Kal -El.

So how did Zod and his army have powers under the red sun?

Comment: You already asked this same question just two weeks ago.

Comment: The answer I was given there was for the current timeline.. no answer was given for alternate timeline.

Comment: From your original question: **"Also in the alternate timeline(where Lois went) Major Zod and his men had kryptonian abilities under RED sun but Kal- El did not. Why? How can this be possible? How can they have their powers under a yellow sun and red sun?"** You are asking the same exact thing here. If you haven't gotten a satisfactory answer to the original question yet, consider offering a bounty.

Comment: ok thanks i will close this question then

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Smallville is not a part of the DC Superman canon and this episode is a hot mess.

Here are some of the problems:

- The episode in question is called Pandora and in it Zod has Tess build him a “solar tower” which in reality takes yellow sun radiation and converts it into red Kryptonian radiation which gets transmitted to satellites and beamed back down to Earth.

  This apparently gives Zod and his Kandorians super powers while leaving Clark powerless under the red radiation.  (Huh?)
- When the solar tower was destroyed, this gave Clark his powers back and de-powered Zod. However, Alia still had super speed.
- Blue Kryptonite only takes powers away, which is why earlier, Jor-El zaps the orb with blue K.

So, what's going on?

Tess mentioned that she helped Zod into power. So, perhaps Tess used some LexCorp technology during the conversion of yellow to red radiation to overcome blue K and red radiation to give the Kandorians powers while taking Clark's away.

Comment: You are just repeating the events of the episode and offering speculation.. od you have any references??